# How does a queueing service like RabbitMQ operate on a cluster?

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue

I understand how a queueing service works on its own, but I don't get how it would work on a cluster?

Are the same messages sent to every queue to mitigate damage if one queue fails? or are they load balanced to each queue?

Additionally, if they are load balanced on each queue, does that eliminate the need for a service like Celery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From rabbitmq offical documentation :

1 - How does a queueing service like RabbitMQ operate on a cluster?

**Clustering**

> All data/state required for the operation of a RabbitMQ broker is
>   replicated across all nodes. An exception to this are message queues,
>   which by default reside on one node, though they are visible and
>   reachable from all nodes. To replicate queues across nodes in a
>   cluster, see the documentation on [high availability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) (note: this guide
>   is a prerequisite for mirroring).
>
> Nodes are Equal Peers Some distributed systems have leader and
>   follower nodes. This is generally not true for RabbitMQ. All nodes in
>   a RabbitMQ cluster are equal peers: there are no special nodes in
>   RabbitMQ core. This topic becomes more nuanced when queue mirroring
>   and plugins are taken into consideration but for most intents and
>   purposes, all cluster nodes should be considered equal

2 - Are the same messages sent to every queue to mitigate damage if one queue fails?

**Queue Mirroring**

> By default, contents of a queue within a RabbitMQ cluster are located
>   on a single node (the node on which the queue was declared). This is
>   in contrast to exchanges and bindings, which can always be considered
>   to be on all nodes. Queues can optionally be made mirrored across
>   multiple nodes.
>
> Each mirrored queue consists of one master and one or more mirrors.
>   The master is hosted on one node commonly referred as the master node.
>   Each queue has its own master node. All operations for a given queue
>   are first applied on the queue's master node and then propagated to
>   mirrors. This involves enqueueing publishes, delivering messages to
>   consumers, tracking acknowledgements from consumers and so on.
>
> Queue mirroring implies a cluster of nodes. It is therefore not
>   recommended for use across a WAN (though of course, clients can still
>   connect from as near and as far as needed).
>
> Messages published to the queue are replicated to all mirrors.
>   Consumers are connected to the master regardless of which node they
>   connect to, with mirrors dropping messages that have been acknowledged
>   at the master. Queue mirroring therefore enhances availability, but
>   does not distribute load across nodes (all participating nodes each do
>   all the work).
>
> If the node that hosts queue master fails, the oldest mirror will be
>   promoted to the new master as long as it synchronised. Unsynchronised
>   mirrors can be promoted, too, depending on queue mirroring parameters.
>
> There are multiple terms commonly used to identify primary and
>   secondary replicas in a distributed system. This guide typically uses
>   "master" to refer to the primary replica of a queue and "mirror" for
>   secondary replicas. However, you will find "slave" used here and
>   there. This is because RabbitMQ CLI tools historically have been using
>   the term "slave" to refer to secondaries. Therefore both terms are
>   currently used interchangeably but we'd like to eventually get rid of
>   the legacy terminology.

For more information : https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html